# Primary constructor parameter declared using val allows to change the value

Tags: scala, immutability, default-value

As shown in below code parameters in primary constructor are defined with default values and `val` it means values of those parameters should not change.
But still why the values changing while initializing the constructor

```
//Why values of Aname and Cname is getting overwritten      
class GFG(val Aname: String = "Ank", val Cname: String = "Constructors") {
  def display() = {
    println("Author name: " + Aname)
    println("Chapter name: " + Cname)

  }
}
//object main
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    var obj = new GFG("a", "b")
    obj.display()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

`class GFG(val Aname: String = "Ank", val Cname: String = "Constructors")`

you're creating a class with a constructor with default parameters. These values will be used only if you don't provide them explicitly. That means you can do:

```
new GFG("a", "b") //both parameters provided, no default values are used -> GFG(a,b)

new GFG("a") //only first parameter provided, second default value is used -> GFG(a,Constructors)

new GFG() // no parameters provided explicitly, only default values are used -> GFG(Ank,Constructors)
```

As you can see that way, you can't use the default value for `Aname` but explicit for `Cname`, but it's possible if you used named parameters:

```
new GFG(Cname = "b") // GFG(Ank, b)
```

Comment: So does that means only within the constructor body you are not allowed to change the value of those parameters?

Comment: Since they're **vals** you cannot reassign them. The point is, that here `val Aname: String = "Ank"` you're not really assigning **val**. You are just providing *default* value in case it is not passed explicitly during method invocation.

Answer (score 3):

`Val`s can be assign a value during initialisation but cannot be changed **after** initialisation, for example

```
var obj = new GFG("a", "b") // ok
obj.Aname // res0: String = a
obj.Aname = "foo" // Error: reassignment to val
```

Comment: The output of above program is                                                                          
Author name: a
Chapter name: b -- my question is I have declared both parameters with val and default values then why those values are not coming in output and why they are getting overwritten

Comment: Default parameters are used only if explicit arguments are not passed in. When you do `new GFG("a", "b")`, then you explicitly pass in `"a"` and `"b"`, thus defaults are not used.